# Who deleted the message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I made a logs script for deleted messages and I wanted it to show who deleted the message
I've tried several combinations, `${message.author}` shows who sent the message and not who deleted it

Script:

```js
client.on('messageDelete', (message, oldMessage, newMessage, messageDelete) => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1026979529387950132');
  const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(
      `<:7889discordchat:1046476120297582622> ‣ LOG | Mensagem Deletada.`,
    )
    .setColor('#10fee4')
    .setFooter({ text: `© ${client.user.username} 2023` })
    .setThumbnail(`${client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048 })}`)
    .setTimestamp(new Date())
    .setDescription(
      `**<:1288discordrole:1028430849915498606> ‣ Autor da mensagem**  \n> **Usuário:** ${message.author} \n> **ID:** ${message.author.id} \n\n**<:7889discordchat:1046476120297582622> ‣ Canal:** \n> ${message.channel} \n\n**Mensagem deletada:** \n \`\`\`${message.content}\`\`\``,
    );
  channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with just the message params. You can however, check the audit log (assuming your bot has the permissions).

First, fetch the audit log using `message.guild.fetchAuditLogs()`

In `fetchAuditLogs()` you can pass the type and optionally, the limit like so:

```
const { AuditLogEvent } = require("discord.js");

message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete, limit: 1 })
```

Then, you can access the fetched log:

```
.then(auditLog => { const executor = auditLog.entries.first().executor })
```

Finally, we get the username of the executor using `executor.username`

###### You can read the audit log entries documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry) and the documentation about `guild#fetchAuditLogs()` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs)

Comment: Can't get it to work, could you change it for me?

Comment: What do you mean by can't get it work? Do you receive any error?

Comment: @Tetie, the `messageDelete` event takes a single parameter (`message`), so `oldMessage`, `newMessage`,  and`messageDelete` will be `undefined`. I changed `newMessage` to `message` in your answer.

Comment: no, I just can't make the change, I'm not very good at javascript. Sorry for any typos I'm using google translator

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros thank you, I just looked at their params without realising that. Anyways, Skyy are you sure you're passing the right params? Are you having an error? Can you please provide us more information about the problem you're having?

Comment: No worries, another tiny error is that `first()` is a method on a collection, so it should be `auditLog.entries.first().executor`

Comment: I made the changes and I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: executor is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you're using executor in the right scope? If you want to use it outside the arrow function you can await fetching the logs and define it later.

`const auditLog = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete, limit: 1 });`

And then: `const executor = auditLog.entries.first().executor`

Comment: I put the script up there, could you modify it for me?

Comment: Define the `fetchAuditLogs()` in async and then use that variable to get the executor. Instead of using `.then()` you can put it after declaring the variable:
`const auditLog = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete, limit: 1 }); const executor = auditLog.entries.first().executor;`

Comment: Note: When a message is deleted, the "messageDelete" event will be triggered regardless of whether the message was deleted by the person who sent it or by someone else with the proper permissions. This means that the message deletion may not always appear in the Audit Logs.

Comment: To account for his above, you can check if the auditLog `target `(the user of the message which got deleted) matches `message.author`.